# What is the Secure Enclave ECIES Encrypted data format?

Tags: ios, encryption, aes-gcm, ecies

I created a assymetric EC key pair in secure enclave (). The public key of the key pair will be sent to my backend service which then uses it to encrypt the data (`kSecKeyAlgorithmECIESEncryptionCofactorX963SHA512AESGCM`). The encrypted data will be sent to the iOS device inorder to decrypt using the private key in the secure enclave.

I need to know the exact options for my ECIES algorthm which I should use it in my backend service.

1. What is the Curve name ?
2. Cofactor to be used?
3. What is AES-GCM key size and block size?
4. What should be the format of the encrypted data ?
5. What is the tag 16 bytes supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

1. Curve used is kSecp256r1
2. Cofactor - 1
3. AES-GCM key Size 128 bits
4. Encrypted Data format [Uncompressed Ephemeral Public Key (65 bytes)][Encrypted Data (length of raw data)][Tag (16 bytes)]
5. AES GCM enryption's Tag

Comment: Thank you for following up with the answer!